# Can we implement "White, Gray, Black" DFS with stack instead of using recursive call

Tags: c++, algorithm, depth-first-search

I am trying to implement "White Gray Black DFS" using stack.

The concept of White Gray Black is below:

1. if a node is not yet visited, it is `White`.
2. if a node is just pushed in stack, but its neighbors are not yet processed. (DFS stack is not empty, DFS process has yet traversed to the branch child), the node is marked `Gray`.
3. if a node and all its child node are processed, it is marked `Black`.

For (3):

- if DFS reaches the end of the branch, the node doesn't have any child nodes, the node is marked `Black`
- with recursive return, all parents nodes can be "backtracked" and changed from `Gray` to `Black`

Now I want to implement the same thing, but instead of using recursive call, I use stack to implement DFS traversing. A problem arises: I cannot backtrack to parent nodes to mark them as `Black`

The sample problem is on this Leetcode link: https://leetcode.com/problems/find-eventual-safe-states/

My current attempt so far:

```
class Solution {
    private:
        vector<int> visited;   
        // mark nodes as Not Visited=0; "In DFS Progress" = 1; at terminal, all processed and connected to terminal = 2
        // if revisiting In Progress node => a back-edge is found.
        bool dfs(vector<vector<int>>& graph, int node, vector<int>& result){
            stack<int> dfsStack;           
            dfsStack.push(node);
            while (!dfsStack.empty()){
                int currNode = dfsStack.top();
                dfsStack.pop();
                // if currNode connect to a node in In Progress
                if (currNode == 1){
                    return false;
                }   
                // mark gray, black for nodes in DFS progress, terminal nodes;
                if (graph[currNode].size()==0){              // mark terminal node as 2
                    visited[currNode] = 2;
                    // set all parents node as 2 ===>>>> HOW TO DO THIS???? 
                }
                else 
                    visited[currNode] = 1;                    // mark node in progress as 1
                // process neighbor:
                for (int i = 0; i < graph[currNode].size(); i++){
                    int nextNode = graph[currNode][i];
                    dfsStack.push(nextNode);
                }
            }
            return true; 
        }
    public:
    vector<int> eventualSafeNodes(vector<vector<int>>& graph) {
        vector<int> result;
        visited.resize((graph.size(),0));                   // all nodes are not yet visited
        for (int node=0; node<graph.size(); node++){
            if (dfs(graph, node, result)
                result.push_back(node);
        }
        return result; 
    }
};
```

I am learning, and to deepen my understanding, I have a habit of implementing every thing with a few methods.

Comment: You can implement *every* recursion using stacks (in fact that's what a compiler outputs / a runtime does), but why would you want to do so ?

Comment: When you look at the top of the stack, don't pop immediately. If the node is white then mark it grey and push all its neighbors onto the stack. If it is grey, then mark it black and pop it from the stack then continue processing the stack. When pushing neighbours, if you encounter a grey one you know it's a cycle.

Answer (score 2):

When you implement DFS recursively, the recursive call to process the child uses the call stack to remember the parent node and the current position in the parent's list of children.

When the child is complete, processing of the processing of the parent node continues, which includes detecting when there are no more children and any final processing of the parent, like "marking it black".

Your iterative implementation does not work like this.  When you start processing the parent, you push *all* its children on the stack and forget about the parent.  The stack doesn't contain the nodes in progress like it does in the recursive version. It contains the nodes that you have yet to visit. That means you didn't remember the information required to do any final parent processing.

You need to make your iterative implementation work more like the recursive one by changing what you remember.  There are many different ways.  For example, instead of using a stack of nodes to remember all unprocessed children, you can you a node stack and a position stack, to remember the current parent and position in the child list just like the recursive version.  Since you are using the same type for nodes and positions, you could even alternate them on the same stack.

But note:  You seem to be using DFS for cycle detection.  Because of the extra complications that we're talking about here, I usually use [Kahn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn%27s_algorithm) for that.